# How to convert epoch time to normal time?

Tags: apex

how do i convert epoch time  to normal time? Is there code /methods you can point me to?

```
 1385423439  --> 25/11/2013 23:50:39
```

it's easy in java

```
long epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse("01/01/1970 01:00:00").getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the [DateTime static methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Datetime_static_methods.htm). You can do it as follows:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(1385423439 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

String x = "1382139200000";

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

long milliSeconds= Long.parseLong(x);

System.out.println(milliSeconds);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);

System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime epochDate = DateTime.newInstance(1970, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);

DateTime calculatedDate = epochDate.addSeconds(1326240000);


System.debug(calculatedDate);
```